# Pyvenv cannot create virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

Usually I use `virtualenv` for python2.x. After some bitter experience with `unicode` encoding/decoding clash, I decided to upgrade to 3.x, But I can't create a virtualenv using pyvenv.

```
$ pyvenv-3.4 env
Error: Command '['/home/user/delete_this/env/bin/python3.4', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Also I'd be grateful if someone points to a good virtual environment for python3.x since I see a lot of options.

Comment: Can you try to run ensurepip command by hand to see what it outputs?

Comment: After some goggling, I found it's a bug `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847` :(

Answer (score 3):

**Here's an approach that is fairly O/S agnostic**...

Both the `pyvenv` and `python` commands themselves include a `--without-pip` option that enable you to work around this issue; without resorting to `setuptool` or other headaches. Taking note of my `inline comments` below, here's how to do it, and is very easy to understand:

```
user$ pyvenv --without-pip ./pyvenv.d          # Create virtual environment this way;
user$ python -m venv --without-pip ./pyvenv.d  # --OR-- this newer way. Both work.

user$ source ./pyvenv.d/bin/activate  # Now activate this new virtual environment.
(pyvenv.d) user$

# Within it, invoke this well-known script to manually install pip(1) into /pyvenv.d:
(pyvenv.d) user$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python

(pyvenv.d) user$ deactivate           # Next, reactivate this virtual environment,
user$ source ./pyvenv.d/bin/activate  # which will now include the pip(1) command.
(pyvenv.d) user$

(pyvenv.d) user$ which pip            # Verify that pip(1) is indeed present.
/path/to/pyvenv.d/bin/pip

(pyvenv.d) user$ pip install --upgrade pip # And finally, upgrade pip(1) itself;
(pyvenv.d) user$                           # although it will likely be the
                                           # latest version. And that's it!
```

I hope this helps. \(◠﹏◠)/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just directly use third-party virtualenv install by `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`, because you are already familiar with it when using python2