# Where is the ensurepip module source code? pyvenv returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Apparently `pyvenv-3.4` is not working correctly in ubuntu 14.10. So I need to grab the `ensurepip` module and drop it into the lib folder? And my googling skills seem to be busted, because I have not been able to find the source code.

I am getting running `pyvenv-3.4 $(pwd)/test`:

```
Error: Command '['/home/bob/Desktop/test/bin/python3.4', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

See:

- #17 from: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

Related:

- [pyvenv-3.4 returned non-zero exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123150/pyvenv-3-4-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)
- [Pyvenv cannot create virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180319/pyvenv-cannot-create-virtual-environment)

Or is it recommended to use virtualenv as suggested in the second related link?

Answer (score 6):

Found it:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.2/Python-3.4.2.tgz

Extract it and copy `ensurepip` to `/usr/lib/python3.4`

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, it helped me out.

Comment: @Crispy It looks like it may have backported See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847/comments/72 ... so `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` may also work now? Also no problem. Glad it helped :)

Comment: This worked for me but using Python 3.5's link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz. I used `tar xzf` on the folder, then `cd` into `Lib` and then ran `copy -R ensurepip /usr/lib/python3.5`